# sql server calculate value according to pecentage and add and group them according to uid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table `temp_calpoints1`

```
orderid processid uid ordervalue percent
1       1         16  33000      10
1       2         4   33000      10
1       3         5   33000      10
1       4         5   33000      20
1       5         4   700000     10
2       1         4   100000     10
2       2         4   100000     10
2       3         5   100000     10
2       4         4   100000     20
2       5         4   700000     10
2       6         1   700000     6
2       6         4   700000     6
2       6        16   700000     6
4       5         5   700000     10
5       1        16   700000     10
```

I want to get the output

percentage value of ordervalue 
for eg in 1st record     10/100*33000=3300

I need to add all these values and group them acccording to uid

```
  uid  totalvalue
     1     xxx
     4     xxx
     5     xxx
     16    xxx
```

I tried this but some how its not working

```
SELECT
  processid,
  SUM(ordervalue) AS [TotalSales]
FROM [dbo].temp_calpoints1
GROUP BY [uid]
```

Comment: You are selecting processid, but it's not in grouping clause (uid instead).

Comment: How do envisage the percentage value working when the overall output is grouped by uid?

Comment: add the percentage value for each uid and display that value as total value in front of uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this option

```
SELECT [uid], SUM(([percent] / 100.00) * ordervalue) AS total 
FROM dbo.test46
GROUP BY [uid]
```

Result:

```
uid total
1   42000.000000
4   225300.000000
5   89900.000000
16  115300.000000
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d2ad/1)